# Dynamic Linq with Where and ObjectParameter produce wrong results

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic
I have this code :

```
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic
.....
Dim mylist As IQueryable(Of Myobject)
Dim ob1 As New List(Of ObjectParameter)
Dim dynstr as string=string.empty

dynstr += "id= @id"
ob1.Add(New ObjectParameter("id", 26))
mylist=context.MyObjects.Where(dynstr,ob1.ToArray()).Tolist
```

I'm expecting that MyList contain only 1 object with id=26 , but MyList contains all the objects inside MyObjects. So it seems that the Where clause has no effect.

What's wrong ?
Thank you !

**Edited** : if I change the dynstr to : dynstr+="id=26" everything works as excpected. So it seems that when using ObjectParamter inside the Where clause , the string "dynstr" doesn't take the values form "ob1.toarray". 
What should I do ?

Comment: not sure if it's typo: ob1.Add() is missing the closing parenthesis ")"

Comment: the parenthesis was an error when typing . Has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Are you using `id = @id`, or `it.id = @id` as per [your post on the MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eab86dfa-9a16-449d-8de7-ff97b52bc20d/dynamic-linq-with-where-and-objectparameter-doesnt-work?forum=adodotnetentityframework)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using numbered parameters instead of `ObjectParameters`:

```
Dim mylist As IQueryable(Of Myobject)
Dim ob1 As New List(Of Object)
Dim dynstr as string = string.empty

dynstr += "id = @0"
ob1.Add(26)

mylist = context.MyObjects.Where(dynstr, ob1.ToArray()).Tolist
```

I suspect the library you're using pre-dates Entity Framework, and therefore doesn't know about the `ObjectParameter` type.